# Keylogger API and converting to a string

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook

I'm attempting to write a simple keylogger that will check typed words against a blacklist and fire a screenshot when a word is triggered. This is because we have a new PREVENT agenda that we have to use in UK schools to capture any possible extremist views.

I've been looking at the Keylogger API from https://github.com/fabriciorissetto/KeystrokeAPI

I'm using the following code as a test but i'm trying to add the characters to a string so i can then fire a comparison with a word list when the user presses the spacebar. The trouble i'm having is that i cannot convert character into a string. Is it possible do this so i can append it to another string a whilst waiting for a spacebar key?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var api = new KeystrokeAPI())
    {
        api.CreateKeyboardHook((character) => { Console.Write(character); });
        Application.Run();
    }
}
}
```

This is what i have so far, the error i get is on the if statement converting character to a string.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string line = "";

        using (var api = new KeystrokeAPI())
        {                             
            api.CreateKeyboardHook((character) => {

                line += character.ToString();

                if (character.ToString() = "space")
                {
                    Console.Write("Spacebar Hit");
                }

                Console.Write(character.KeyCode);

            });


            Application.Run();
        }

    }
```

Comment: What else have you tried so far, anything such as appending the chars to an array, or concatenating to a string as long as the pressed key is not equal to Spacebar and then performing your comparison?

Comment: You can compare the keys by enum, instead of by space. `if (character.KeyCode = KeyCode.Space)`

Comment: I added an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Edit. 
I rewrote this. 
Captures both spaces and enter commands

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string line = string.Empty;

    using (var api = new KeystrokeAPI())
    {
        api.CreateKeyboardHook((character) => {

            if (character.KeyCode.ToString() == "Space" || character.KeyCode.ToString() == "Return")
            {
                if(BannedWordsCheck(line))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Banned Word Typed: " + line);
                }

                line = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                line += character.KeyCode.ToString();
            }
        });

        Application.Run();
    }
}

static bool BannedWordsCheck(string word)
{
    if(word.ToLower().Contains("terror"))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving in your code is due to the following line
`if (character.ToString() = "space")`

You are attempting to assign the string literal "space" to `character.ToString()`, I also have this error in my comment which I can't edit anymore.

Here's a snippet that will check the key code against an enum instead of a string, it will then call the `HandleComparison` method if Space was pressed, and then clear out the `StringBuilder`

The only issue I found here is that pressing Shift will prefix the string with `<shift>`, so some additional logic will have to be applied for action keys, but this is a base to get you started with a working code sample.

I hope this helps.

```
class Program
{
    private static StringBuilder builder;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var api = new KeystrokeAPI())
        {
            builder = new StringBuilder();
            api.CreateKeyboardHook(HandleKeyPress);
            Application.Run();
        }
    }

    private static void HandleKeyPress(KeyPressed obj)
    {
        // To be more reliable, lets use the KeyCode enum instead
        if (obj.KeyCode == KeyCode.Space)
        {
            // Spacebar was pressed, let's check the word and flush the StringBuilder
            HandleComparison(builder.ToString());
            builder.Clear();

            return;
        }
        // Space wasn't pressed, let's add the word to the StringBuilder
        builder.Append(obj);
    }
    // Handle comparison logic here, I.E check word if exists on blacklist
    private static void HandleComparison(string compareString)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(compareString);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) as a buffer?

something like this

```
var buffer = new StringBuilder();

using (var api = new KeystrokeAPI())
{
    api.CreateKeyboardHook((character) => { 
        if (character.ToString() == " ") 
        {
            //check the word
            CallSomeMethodToCheckWord(buffer.ToString());

            //reset the buffer
            buffer = new StringBuilder();
        } 
        else 
        {
            //ToString returns special characters in it, so you could append here and parse later, or parse here.
            buffer.Append(character.ToString());
        }
    });
    Application.Run();
}
```

Comment: The problem i get with this is the same as i get in my original code. Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'Keystroke.API.CallbackObjects.KeyPressed' KeyLogger

Comment: Okay, I see what is happening.  `CreateKeyboardHook` has a parameter with an action that uses `KeyPressed`.  In their example, character is a `KeyPressed` object, not a char.  You are in luck, because that object has a method [ToString()](https://github.com/fabriciorissetto/KeystrokeAPI/blob/master/Keystroke.API/Entities/CallbackObjects/KeyPressed.cs) that should give you a string with the character pressed.  Keep in mind that for special keys it will have something like <shift> that you will need to parse.  Editing code above to show this.